# Can "hidden in plain sight" be used in a sentence?

Tags: phrases, expressions, cinema

I learned from google that "[Hidden in Plain Sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_in_Plain_Sight)" is a movie title. Since I caught up the expression without context, I tried to use it. Now, I'm not sure whether it can be used without making reference to the movie.

Can I say "This [...] was hidden in plain sight" referring to something that should have been obvious for everyone involved, but was overlooked due to way people approached the problem.

The context is a non-technical introduction to an academic thesis.

Comment: It's also an Xbox title. And it is used in something like your context: [Independent newspaper](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/hidden-in-plain-sight-how-the-needs-of-the-poor-are-being-ignored-2278989.html)

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HiddenInPlainSight

Comment: Let me google that for you: http://bit.ly/17WzdIu (link broke so I bitly'd it, it goes to google.com).

Comment: Though you can say it, I don't think you should; you should [avoid idioms in academic works.](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/608/)

Comment: @Luc http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/203101

Comment: @terdon And yet he could have googled it couldn't he?

Comment: @Luc yes, I am just pointing out that lmgtfy links are frowned upon as a rude way of telling the OP that more research was needed.

Comment: @Luc Great use of the wildcard character (*) in your google query. Didn't know that. (Yes, I could have figured this out myself.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can. "Hidden in plain sight" isn't a widely known idiom however, so make sure it's obvious to your reader.

Answer (score 2):

An Ngram ( http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hidden+in+plain+sight&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share= ) shows that the near-paradoxical idiom has been used since at least 1901. The sudden surge round about 1981 can't be due to the film - I'm wondering if Chomsky popularised the term.